# PHP Global variable scope not the same between functions

Tags: php, scope, global

I have a question about how php gauges the scope when using the global command with variables.
I have two functions in the same scope of my php code.
In loopitback, the global command works as expected.
In loopitback_two the global command doesn't grab the $global_arr.
I did do a test using session vars and it works fine.

It seems to me that these two functions are identical, so I look to someone with more wisdom.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

EDIT: ADDED MORE CODE

```
$global_arr = array(array());

function save_the_arr($sql_row1)
{
    global $global_arr;

    POPULATED ARRAY

    $_SESSION['queue']=$global_arr;
}

function loopitback($max)
{
    global $global_arr;

    $i = 0;
    while($i<$max)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $global_arr[$i][0] . "</td></tr>";
        $i = $i+1;
        if($global_arr[$i][0]==NULL OR $global_arr[$i][0]=="")
            $i=$max;
    }
}

function loopitback_two($max)
{
    global $global_arr;

    $i = 0;
    while($i<$max)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $global_arr[$i][0] . "</td></tr>";
        $i = $i+1;
        if($global_arr[$i][0]==NULL OR $global_arr[$i][0]=="")
            $i=$max;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the global variables at your `construct`.Because even you define it as GLOBAL, its instance only within that function.And it will redefine it in the next function if you didnt mention it on `construct` like

```
function __construct() {
    global $global_arr;
}
function loopitback() {
    //Do something with it
}
function loopitback_two() {
    //Do something with it
}
```

**EDIT:** In case of your edit,define the `$global_arr` as `global variable` while it is initiaizing..

```
global $global_arr = array();

function save_the_arr($sql_row1) {

}
```

See [**THIS**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) if you need more information..

Comment: What do you mean by initializing it at your `construct`? Try providing some example code.

Comment: OP didn't even mention whether this was OOP or procedural though.

Comment: In case of that..I have suggested my ans

Comment: @Gautam3164 Thanks for the quick answer, I added the construct function.
Removed my declaration of $global_arr and tried it with and without "global $global_arr" inside the loopitback funcs.
EDIT: I should add, when I made these changes, neither of the functions performed properly.
But still no luck.

Comment: See the link http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php that may helps for you,as related to my ans

Comment: @Gautam3164 Thank you for your help, I've found my issue. I didn't have "global var" in a previous function.
I suppose I am still thinking in C.
I appreciate the help you have given.